# Want to call shortcode after every blog post title automatically

Tags: shortcode

i want to call shortcode after every blog post title automatically. It's a search box which already using on pages when i place the shortcode, now i want to add it on my 500+ posts once, is there any hook which can do that, may be the_post hook or something else !
shortcode is like [my_shortcode], can anyone have in this regard ?

Thanks.